# Change Background color in Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, background, kivy, screen

I am trying to change the background color to white or remove the black screen in front of my first page screen. My second and third screen backgrounds show but the first has a black screen in front of it. It looks like the screen is blocking what I want to show until I click to the next screen. I'm not sure how to put the black screen in the back of my screen or remove it.

screen.kv

```
<Login>:    
 BoxLayout:
      canvas.before:
           Color:
                rgb: 255, 255, 255
           Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
      orientation: 'vertical'
      size: root.size
      padding: [150, 25, 150, 25]
      spacing: 50

      Image:
           source:'NextStep.Final.png'
           texture: self.texture
           size: 0, 100
           size_hint: 1, None

      Label:         
           text: 'Welcome to A.M.B.L.E'
           font_size: 32
           color: 0, 0, 0, 1



      Label:         
           text: 'Welcome to A.M.B.L.E'
           font_size: 32
           color: 0, 0, 0, 1




      BoxLayout:
           orientation: 'vertical'
           size_hint: 1, 10

           Label:
                text: 'Username:'
                font_size: 18
                halign: 'left'
                text_size: root.width-20, 20
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1

           TextInput:
               id: login
               multiline:False
               font_size: 28



           BoxLayout:
               orientation: 'vertical'
               size_hint: 1, 10

           Label:
                text: 'Password:'
                halign: 'left'
                font_size: 18
                text_size: root.width-20, 20
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1

          TextInput:
               id: password
               multiline:False
               password:True
               font_size: 28

          Button:
              text: 'Login'
              font_size: 24
              size_hint: 1, 5
              color: 1, 1, 1, 1
              background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1


              on_press: root.manager.current = 'Connected'


<Connected>:
     canvas.before:
          Color:
               rgb: 1, 1, 1 
          Rectangle:
               pos: self.pos
               size: self.size
     BoxLayout:

      orientation: 'vertical'
      size: root.size
      padding: [150, 25, 150, 25]
      spacing: 50

      Image:
           source:'NextStep.Final.png'
           texture: self.texture
           size: 0, 100
           size_hint: 1, None

      Label:         
           text: 'Welcome to A.M.B.L.E'
           font_size: 32
           color: 0, 0, 0, 1




      Button:
           text:'View Patient'
           font_size: 18
           color: 1, 1, 1, 1
           background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
           on_press: root.manager.current = 'Patient'





      Button:           
           text:'Patient Goals'
           font_size: 18
           color: 1, 1, 1, 1
           background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1



      Button:
           text:'Patient Progress'
           font_size: 18
           color: 1, 1, 1, 1
           background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1


      Button:
           text:'Help'
           font_size: 18
           color: 1, 1, 1, 1
           background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1


<Patient>:
     canvas.before:
          Color:
               rgb: 1, 1, 1 
          Rectangle:
               pos: self.pos
               size: self.size
     BoxLayout:

      orientation: 'vertical'
      size: root.size
      padding: [150, 25, 150, 25]
      spacing: 50

      Image:
           source:'NextStep.Final.png'
           texture: self.texture
           size: 0, 100
           size_hint: 1, None

      Label:         
           text: 'Welcome to A.M.B.L.E'
           font_size: 32
           color: 0, 0, 0, 1



<Manager>:
     id: screen_manager 

     login: login
     connected: connected 
     patient: patient 

     Login:
         id: login 
         name: 'Login'
         manager: screen_manager 

     Connected:
         id: connected
         name: 'Connected'
         manager: screen_manager 

     Patient:
         id: patient
         name: 'Patient'
         manager: screen_manager
```

patient.py

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, 
SlideTransition 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Color 
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle 
from kivy.core.window import Window 

import os

from connected import Connected


class Login(Screen):
    pass

class Connected(Screen):
    pass


class Patient(Screen):
    pass 


class Manager(ScreenManager):

    patient = ObjectProperty(None)
    connected = ObjectProperty(None)
    login = ObjectProperty(None)

class ScreensApp(App):

    def build(self):

        m = Manager(transition=SlideTransition())   
        return m



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreensApp().run()
```

Comment: After reformatting your `kv` file, it seems to work fine for me. Can you add a screenshot to show what the problem is?

Comment: @RanyeMclendon: Rename your kv file from `screen.kv` to `screens.kv`

Comment: It worked after reformatting. Thank you